# Eliminar legenda de gráfico radar criado com o módulo openpyxl em Python

Tags: python, openpyxl

gostaria de poder eliminar a legenda do gráfico gerado no excel pelo programa Pyhton usando o módulo openpyxl abaixo:

```
 from openpyxl import workbook
 from openpyxl import load_workbook
 from openpyxl import worksheet
 from openpyxl.chart import RadarChart, Reference

 wb = load_workbook(filename = 'grafico.xlsx')

 ws = wb.create_sheet('Grafico')

 rows = [
     ['Equipe', "Grau de Maturidade"],
     ['Equipe 1', 2.3,],
     ['Equipe 2', 3.4],
     ['Equipe 3', 4.2],
     ['Equipe 4', 2.1],
     ['Equipe 5', 3.8],
     ['Equipe 6', 2.8],
]

for row in rows:
ws.append(row)

chart = RadarChart()
chart.type = "marker"
labels = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_row=7)
data = Reference(ws, min_col=2, max_col=7, min_row=1, max_row=7)
chart.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
chart.set_categories(labels)
chart.style = 26
chart.title = "Grau de Maturidade"
chart.y_axis.delete = False
chart.y_axis.scaling.min = 0
chart.y_axis.scaling.max = 5

ws.add_chart(chart, "A17")

wb.save(filename = 'grafico.xlsx')
```

Consegui encontrar os parâmetros para definir a posição da legenda, mas não consegui excluir a legenda. Para este meu gráfico, ela é desnecessária.

Outra questão também é quando amplio o tamanho do gráfico no excel, o excel automaticamente ajusta o intervalo das linhas guias do eixo y e começa a mostrar de 0.5 em 0.5, quando eu gostaria de manter de 1 em 1 ponto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Obrigado!

Comment: Como sou novo por aqui, gostaria de entender porque minha pergunta foi classificada como sem esforço de pesquisa ou não clara...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As respostas para meus 2 problemas são:

Eliminar a legenda do gráfico:

```
chart.legend = None
```

Manter as linhas de grade do eixo com o valor de 1 em 1:

```
chart.y_axis.majorUnit = 1
```